# Objective C - Change text size in Action Sheet for iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uialertcontroller

I have an iPad app which already works on iOS 7.  I used to reduce the text size in the action sheet buttons with this code:

```
- (void) willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
  for (UIView *subview in actionSheet.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
      UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
      button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0];
    }
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to do the same on iOS 8 with `UIAlertController` and `UIAlertAction`.  Although the `UIAlertController` has a view with subviews, it doesn't seem to have any `UIButton` or `UILabel` in it.

Comment: You can't do this in iOS 8. It's all different. Better to right your own or find a 3rd party `UIActionSheet` replacement that allows for customizations.

Comment: Yes, I ended up creating a view controller with a single button inside of a popover controller.  Thank you.

Comment: This answer may also help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26463892/3219089

Answer (score 0):

You CAN do that on iOS8. Just subclass UIAlertController, check code below:

```c
@interface AlertController : UIAlertController

@end

@implementation AlertController

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

  // Search for labels and change font
  [self changeLabelsFontInView:self.view];
}

- (void)changeLabelsFontInView:(UIView *)view {
  if (view.subviews.count > 0) {
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
      [self changeLabelsFontInView:subview];
    }
  } else {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
      [(UILabel *)view setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:35.0F]];
    }
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works because I believe `UIAlertController` has no `UILabel`'s, but I will give it a try.